# Insert object in between other objects Dart

Tags: dart

Say I have

```
Map<String, double> list = {};
list.putIfAbsent("hello", () => 2.0);
list.putIfAbsent("hi", () => 5.0);
list.putIfAbsent("world", () => 8.0);
```

How could I insert a object so the list goes like this

```
"hello" = 2.0
"hi" = 5.0
"hi there" = 12.0
"world" = 8.0
```

I have found the "hi" object I just need to put the object next to it in the list.

Thanks!

Comment: Your `list` variable are not a list but a `Map`. The order of elements in maps should, in general, not be assumed (especially, as you have discovered, it is hard to keep a specific order of elements in maps without a complete recreation). Lists, however, do have the ability to insert elements at specific indexes: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-core/List/insert.html

Comment: @julemand101 A caveat to that, maps in Dart created with non-const literals will be a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap-class.html), so order is going to be insertion order. As far as I know, there's no way to put an element into a`LinkedHashMap` at a specific position in that order (unless you remove all items past that position and then re-add them after the new element).

Comment: @Abion47 I fully agree. My statement about the order was more about the problem with keeping the created map in some specified order while doing changes to it since, as you also mention, cannot insert into specific positions or do any sorting. The best we can do is `SplayTreeMap` but that is only sorting based on the `key` value and only when inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Your "list" is actually a `Map`.
If the `Map` in question is a `LinkedHashMap` (literals are), then the order of iteration is determined by the order of item addition.

The only way to insert an item in a particular place is to remove every item up until that point, add the item, and then add everything back.

A simpler method would be to remove every item and add them all back in the order you want, like so:

```dart
final entries = list.entries.toList();
entries.insert(2, MapEntry("hi there", 12.0));
list..clear()..addEntries(entries);
```